# How to change content of cell in GridView based on content of another cell?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagridview

I have 2 TemplateField columns in a GridView. One column displays the name of a file (if it exists), the other column has a linkbutton to download the file shown in the first column.

However even if there no file in a specific row, it still contains a download link (it does not do anything when clicked).

I cannot figure out how I can hide the download link in rows which do not have a file.

```html
                          
                       <asp:GridView ID="gvData" runat="server"DataSourceID="mySqlDataSource2">     
                          <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="File Name " SortExpression="FileName">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FileName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FileName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridHeader" ForeColor="#A1ADBB" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Download Config" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="download" runat="server" CausesValidation="false"   OnClick="download_Click"
                                        CommandArgument="<% %>"
                                        CommandName="Download">
                                        <i aria-hidden="true"></i></asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridHeader" ForeColor="#A1ADBB" />
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                          </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>

                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="mySqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ connectionStrings:cs3 %>"
                    ProviderName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" SelectCommand="#$$@#$^"
                    OnSelected="mySqlDataSource_Selected"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Write your code, I can't know which types are your columns and other things

Comment: please post your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this in the LinkButton

```
visible='<%# (Eval("FileName") != null && Eval("FileName") != "") ? true : false %>'
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I have a lot to learn about GridViews. Thank you!